An exercise from Artin
This is a problem from old artin (11.3.10) or new artin (12.3.5):
Consider the map $\varphi : \mathbb{C} [x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} [t]$ defined by $f(x,y)\mapsto f(t^2-t,t^3-t^2)$. Prove that $\ker \varphi$ is a principal ideal and find a generator for this ideal. Prove that the image of $\varphi$ is the set of polynomials $p(t)$ such that $p(0)=p(1)$. Give an intuitive explanation in terms of the geometry of the variety $\{f=0\}$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$.
I know what the kernel and image are, but what is the "intuitive explanation"? The variety is $\{y^2-xy-x^3=0\}$, please give a hint what to prove here. Thanks in advance.

By the first isomorphism theorem, $\varphi$ induces a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism between the ring of global sections of the variety $V$ you found and the ring of global sections of $\mathbb{A}^1$, thus it corresponds to a morphism of varieties $\mathbb{A}^1\to V$. What can you say about this morphism?
